# DateTimePicker UpDown overflow

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I added DateTimePicker on my C# form. I use the format `Time` with `ShowUpDown = true`. When I use the Up/Down buttons, the hour, minute or second increase/decrease. When the seconds overflow (From 59 to 0 or 0 to 59, I would like to increase the minute. Is there a way to do it ?

how it works now:

- TimerPicker = 00:01:59 → press UpKey on second → TimerPicker = 00:01:00
- TimerPicker = 05:00:38 → press DownKey on minute → TimerPicker = 05:59:38

how I would like it works:

- TimerPicker = 00:01:59 → press UpKey on second → TimerPicker = 00:02:00
- TimerPicker = 05:00:38 → press DownKey  on minute → TimerPicker = 04:59:38

Edit:
Here is my code related to the DateTimePicker:

DataGraph.Designer.cs:

```
this.TimePerDivisionPicker = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();
// 
// TimePerDivisionPicker
// 
this.TimePerDivisionPicker.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.TimePerDivisionPicker.CustomFormat = "";
this.TimePerDivisionPicker.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
this.TimePerDivisionPicker.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.On;
this.TimePerDivisionPicker.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(83, 16);
this.TimePerDivisionPicker.Name = "TimePerDivisionPicker";
this.TimePerDivisionPicker.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
this.TimePerDivisionPicker.ShowUpDown = true;
this.TimePerDivisionPicker.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 20);
this.TimePerDivisionPicker.TabIndex = 4;
this.TimePerDivisionPicker.Value = new System.DateTime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0);
this.TimePerDivisionPicker.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TimePerDivisionPicker_ValueChanged);
```

DataGraph.cs:

```
private void TimePerDivisionPicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] temp = TimePerDivisionPicker.Text.Split(':');
    UInt16 tempHours = Convert.ToUInt16(temp[0]);
    UInt16 tempMinutes = Convert.ToUInt16(temp[1]);
    UInt16 tempSecondes = Convert.ToUInt16(temp[2]);
    TimePerDivision = Convert.ToUInt32(tempHours * 3600 + tempMinutes * 60 + tempSecondes);
}
```

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: Is this WinForms? WPF? WebForms? But I don't think this is possible with the normal WinForms control and you may need to look at third party controls or write your own. Maybe wrong though.

Comment: @Strike08 I added the code related to the DateTimePicker.

Comment: @RyanThomas It's a WinForms. If it's impossible, I will try to do it manually thanks to the ValueChanged event, but it's not so easy because the step is not constant and the ValueChanged event is not triggered every time if you hold the click on up or down buttons.

Comment: DTP is not actually a .NET component, it is built into the operating system.  There is very little you can do to customize how it behaves.  Certainly not this, it doesn't generate [a notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bumper-date-and-time-picker-control-reference-notifications) for it.  Component vendors are apt to provide a complete replacement for it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle up/down keys and clicking on up/down arrows. Then compare old time with new time and add hour or minute.

There can be problem if your datetime will go out of range (Minimum/Maximum DateTime)

Not the nicest solution but it works.

```
public class MyTimePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    private Arrow _pressedArrow;
    private DateTime? _oldValue;

    public MyTimePicker()
    {
        Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
        ShowUpDown = true;
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);

        if (!_oldValue.HasValue)
        {
            return;
        }
        var diff = Value - _oldValue.Value;
        _oldValue = null;

        if (_pressedArrow == Arrow.Up)
        {
            if (diff.Minutes < 0)
            {
                Value = Value.AddHours(1);
            }
            else if (diff.Seconds < 0)
            {
                Value = Value.AddMinutes(1);
            }
        }
        else if (_pressedArrow == Arrow.Down)
        {
            if (diff.Minutes > 0)
            {
                Value = Value.AddHours(-1);
            }
            else if (diff.Seconds > 0)
            {
                Value = Value.AddMinutes(-1);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Up: HandleArrow(Arrow.Up); break;
            case Keys.Down: HandleArrow(Arrow.Down); break;
            default: break;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x204e || m.Msg == 0x4e)
        {
            NMHDR nfy = (NMHDR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(NMHDR));
            if (nfy.code == -722)
            {
                NMUPDOWN ud = (NMUPDOWN)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(NMUPDOWN));
                HandleArrow(ud.delta < 0 ? Arrow.Down : Arrow.Up);
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private bool HandleArrow(Arrow arrow)
    {
        _pressedArrow = arrow;
        _oldValue = Value;
        return false;
    }

    private enum Arrow
    {
        Up,
        Down,
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct NMHDR
    {
        public IntPtr hwndFrom;
        public IntPtr idFrom;
        public int code;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct NMUPDOWN
    {
        public NMHDR hdr;
        public int pos;
        public int delta;
    }
}
```